# close parent div add content then open div again with jquery .after

Tags: jquery

I have the below code

```
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

with this jquery

```
jQuery('p:nth-child(5)').after('</div><div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000"></div><div>');
```

I want my output to be this.

```
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    </div><div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000"></div><div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

instead I am getting this.

```
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p><div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000"></div><div></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/2T4AJ/) for example.

Where am I going wrong here?  Or should I be using something other than [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to do this?

Comment: What you're doing is actually a very common mistake made with functions like `.after()`, `.append()`, etc. They don't insert raw html, they insert html elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use unbalanced HTML to change the DOM tree like that.  jQuery requires a balanced block of HTML to be supplied, since each time you pass in HTML like this it's creating a detached DOM tree, not merely inserting the HTML snippet into the source code.

You'll need to create a new `<div>` to hold the image, and another to hold the remaining `<p>` elements, and then use `.append()` to move the excess elements from the first div into the latter, e.g.:

```
var $d = $('div');
var $p = $('p:gt(4)');
if ($p.length) {
    $('<div>').insertAfter($d).append($p);
    $('<div><img src="..."></div>').insertAfter($d);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Z8LR3/

Comment: Also note that the first comment in the [`.after` doc page](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is about this behaviour.

Comment: Works well and great explanation as well. I don't quite understand how :gt is working here.  From what I have seen of :gt in the past shouldn't it be appending to every p gt 4?

Comment: @ak85 no, because I'm using `appendTo`, not `append`.  I'm taking every `p:gt(4)` and moving those _into_ the new `div`, not the other way around.

Comment: thanks. I notice in your fiddle if you only have 2 <p> on the page it still puts the image in at the end.  so I added var count = jQuery("p").length; if (count > 4) so that it only added in this image if there was a certain amount of p tags.

Comment: @ak85 yup, that's what happens if you don't specify your problem properly.  Your question made _zero_ mention of what should happen in the "less than 6" case! ;-)

Comment: @ak85 on the other hand, my rewritten answer (after a night's sleep) now looks cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's .after method can receive only a valid, self contained HTML element.

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

`content: HTML string, DOM element, or jQuery object to insert after each element in the set of matched elements.`

You should instead transfer all of your wanted elements by hand, try using [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
var elements = $('p:nth-child(5)').nextAll('p').detach();
var nextdiv = $("<div></div>).append(elements);
$('.parentDiv').after(nextdiv);
$('.parentDiv').after('<div><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000"></div>');
```

Comment: `$("p:nth-child(n + 5)")` is probably more efficient than `.nextAll('p')` there.

Comment: there's no need to `detach` - the `.append` will do that implicitly.

Comment: @Rodik I don't think that'll work either.  That's why I used `.gt()`